# Humane PostgreSQL interface for non-technical people?

Tags: sql, database, excel, postgresql

I currently have lots of semi-static structured data in a bunch of excel sheets which I'm using on a website. The data changes very rarely, so I essentially load the data (mostly things like copy-text, translations, etc.) directly from excel using Apache POI into memory when I need it. It works great.

However, eventually I'd like to swap over to a proper database, ideally the same PostgreSQL database I'm using for the truly dynamic stuff. However, the advantage of Excel is that all the non-technical people I'm working with can directly edit it and have the changes show up on the website. I'm personally using pgAdmin to manage the DB as a system, but it's too close to the machine for me to trust non-technical people with it.

Is there any generic CRUD admin interface for PostgreSQL that non-technical people can understand? Something like Django's admin interface, exposing the bare minimum of CRUD operations in a easy to use way, without exposing any dangerous knobs or buttons, but not tied to any specific web framework?

Comment: Hmmm, take a look at Navicat Postgresql, maybe it has more authorization settings you can customize...

Comment: Why not use the built in Django admin interface? It sounds like they would work great for this. Converting your Excel spreadsheet to models/classes might seem silly at first, but every time I had to do it, it ended up cleaning a lot of the data and simplifying its maintenance.

Comment: Mainly because I don't really want to install another server in python (not currently using Django) and copy my model definitions into python. If I can't find any standalone admin GUIs i might try it.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/features.php).  While it includes a lot of advanced capabilities geared toward software developers and DBAs, it has the [Edit Grid](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/editgrid.html) tool, which sounds pretty much exactly like what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

How quickly do you need to get the data into the database?

I have this problem all the time.  Typically, I solve it in one of the following ways:

(1) Have the users change the Excel spreadsheets and then have them automatically loaded at night.  The data will be available the next day.

(2) Embed something in Excel to allow users to load the data directly into the database.  The data gets loaded automatically.  This could also be done by have an auto-close macro ni VBA.

(3) Rarely, build an application that loads the data into the spreadsheet and then let's the user modify the data and write it back.

There is not enough information to figure out the best approach.  However, keeping the users in Excel is a good idea, since they are most comfortable with that environment.

Comment: Ideally I'd want to have the data available immediately, but it won't be modified very often, so the performance implications aren't so important as long as it doesn't take an hour to upload or freeze the server for 15 minutes. The excel files are maybe a megabyte in total right now; this isn't big data, but they'll probably grow (slowly). I know excel can do some funky stuff with external data-sources; would setting up a read-from-postgres-write-on-save be possible?